# Closed but not sequentially compact set

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, rational-numbers

I read that the intersection of $Q$ (the rational numbers) with $[0,2]$ 'in' the $Q$ field is closed and bounded but not compact. Let this set be called $E$.

The reason is that there can be Cauchy sequence in $E$ that can converge to a number in $R$, such as the square root of 2. But this sequence does not have any subsequence that converges in $E$, hence $E$ is not sequentially compact..

But why is $E$ closed if it does not contain a limit point? (i.e. the square root of 2)... or are limit points required to be defined on the field where the sequence is taken from? ($Q$ in this case)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The set $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,2]$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ because it can be expressed as the intersection of $\mathbb{Q}$ with a closed subset of $\mathbb R$. And it is true the every limit point of $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,2]$ $\color{red}{\text{in }\mathbb{Q}}$ belongs to $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,2]$, which is consistent with the statement that $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,2]$ is closed $\color{red}{\text{in }\mathbb{Q}}$. So, there is no contradiction here.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now, the 'in Q' part is important

Comment: Note: to be closed is relative (to the ambient space) but being compact is an absolute property (independent of the ambient space).

Comment: This is not correct. The rationals are not closed, not even on the interval [0,2]. There are several sequences of rational numbers that converge to irrationals (see: the Basel problem and the series definition of e)

Comment: Adding to my previous comment: it matters what definition of closed we are considering. I assumed the question was in reference to the real-analysis definition of closed, which I have stated in my answer. The rationals certainly are closed under many operations in the algebraic definition of closed.

Comment: @PatrickCook those sequences you mention do not converge in $\mathbb Q$ just as the sequence $x_n=\frac 1 n$ is a  divergent sequence  in the metric space $(0,1)$ with the usual Euclidean distance.

Comment: @Shashi I suspect this is a problem with what mathematics we are working in. Look at any Advanced Calculus textbook, and the convergence of $\frac{1}{n}$ is usually something discussed in the first few chapters. The definition of convergence that books like these are using is: "A sequence $\{a_n\}$ converges to $a$ if $\forall\epsilon >0~\exists N\in\mathbb{N}~s.t.~\vert a_n - a \vert < \epsilon~\forall n \geq N$."

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,2]$ is not closed.

Using the following definition for closed:
"A set $S$ is said to be closed provided that if $\lbrace a_n\rbrace$ is a sequence in S that converges to $a$ then $a$ is also in $S$"

By counterexample, using the series definition of $e$. We can see that if we let

$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{k=n}\frac{1}{k!}$

then $\lbrace a_n\rbrace\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,2]$ and $a_n$ converges to $e-1$ which is not in $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,2]$. So $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,2]$ is not closed.

---

Moreover, a set is closed and bounded if and only if it is compact. So if $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,2]$ was closed and bounded, then it would have to be compact.