# On the dimension of rationals over real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, compactness

The following two are from *Introductory Functional Analysis* by E Kreyszig:

> 2.5-2 Lemma . A [sequentially] compact subset M of a metric space 
>   is closed and bounded.
>
> The converse of this lemma is in general false.
>
> However, for a finite dimensional normed space we have :
>
> 2.5-3 Theorem. In a finite dimensional normed space 
>   X, any subset $M \subset X$ is [sequentially] compact if and only if M is closed and bounded.

On the other hand, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2754296/closed-but-not-sequentially-compact-set) it shows that $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,2]$ is not sequentially compact thus must be infinite dimensional (over $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$) but any element of $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,2]$ can be written as a multiple of some element in $\Bbb R$ (or $\Bbb C$) times 1 so dimension of $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,2]$ over $\Bbb R$ (or $\Bbb C$) is 1 not infinite! Contradiction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\mathbb Q\cap[0,2]$ is *not* a normed space, there is no contradiction.

On the other hand, $\mathbb R$ is a $1$-dimensional normed space and, indeed, $\mathbb Q\cap[0,2]$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$ whichnot closed and not compact. So, again, there is no contradiction.

Comment: I meant $\mathbb Q\cap[0,2]$ is closed in itself... And why is $\mathbb Q\cap[0,2]$ is not a normed space?

Comment: Because it is not a vector space.